# After a manual update, themes and plugins that were installed (and still in the directory) are not being seen

Tags: plugins, themes, updates, fatal-error

The title pretty much says it all. The files and folders for my various themes and plugins are all intact in their proper path location under wp-content, but the WordPress install is not seeing them.

Additionally, all of the pages within the site are loading a blank white pages (my assumption is that this is a result of the install not seeing any themes).

I'm stumped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No longer stumped. wp-content was owned by root. After running `chown -R apache:apache wp-content`, everything looks to be working correctly.